# 2.0 API get votes

Tags: support, feature-request

I've been searching the 2.0 API for a list of my own (up and down) votes. I don't see them in the API.

I don't think this is a prohibitively resource intensive query or that it can be used to invade people's privacy, but I do see a lot of value being able to obtain this data using the API.

Are they in the API and I'm missing something? If not, would it be possible to add to the 2.0 API?

Comment: I doubt that anything major like this would be added so late in the v2.0 development cycle - but I can't offer any official word so we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: I believe in user_timeline it'd be great to have 2 new timeline_type "upvote" and "downvote", because upvoting/downvoting a question / answer should also be considered activity events